# I need a way to identify which button is being pressed when all of the buttons are being generated by php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using php to generate an undefined amount of divs, and each div is formated the same but has different information being filled in. My issue is I cannot figure out how to identify which div the button that is pressed is within? I would like to be able to know $row["bar_name"] for the button being pressed. i.e. if monday is pressed i need to also know which $row["bar_name"] the monday button was within. I changed the formating of how the div is generated because it is easier to read when it's in html compared to being echoed in php. Any help is appreciated, Thank You!

```
// how the div is being generated (slightly altered for easier readability)
<?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//this is echoed as one string in my actual code
<div id='" . $row["bar_name"] . "'>
    <h3 id='barTitle' class='bar'>" . $row["bar_name"] . "</h3>
    <h6 id='subTitle'>". $row["hourStart"] . "-" . $row["hourEnd"] . "  |  " . $row["area"] . "</h6>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='monday'> Monday </button></th>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='tuesday'> Tuesday </button></th>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='wednesday'> Wednesday </button></th>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='thursday'> Thursday </button></th>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='friday'> Friday </button></th>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='saturday'> Saturday </button></th>
                <th class='dowb'> <button id='sunday'> Sunday </button></th>
                <br>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='barInfo'> <strong> Drinks: </strong></th>
                        <th class='barInfo'> <strong> Food: </strong></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='barInfo' id="dowDrink"> Things to drink</th>
                        <th class='barInfo' id="dowFood"> Things to eat</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <a href='" . $row["profile_page"] . "'> More Info </a>
            <hr>
            </div>
        }
    }
?>

//ajax (its the same code with the names switched out for monday-sunday)
 $("#monday").click(function() {
    var monday = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "barMapPhp.php",
        data: {monday: monday},
        success: function(result){
        jQuery("#dowd").html(result);
        }
      });
  });

// php code that ajax is sent to but im unsure how to proceed from here if i cant specify which $row["bar_name"] div that the button was in

if(isset($_POST["monday"])){
        ???
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple monday buttons, use a class like `.monday` instead of an id to access the button (you are not supposed to have multiple elements with the same id on one page. To identify the specific button

1. Add the bar name to the button as an attribute `bar_name=""` and access it using `$(this).attr('bar_name')` in the jQuery `.click()` callback function.
2. Use the jQuery `.parent()` method to find the parent `<div>` of the button and fetch its `id` (bar_name) attribute:

   $('.monday').parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

You can find the container that matches a given selector without knowing the html structure by using `.closest()`.

Also, you don't need multiple functions for each day at all, you can compute the day from the name of the button given your setup. But beware, `id` attributes should be unique, even though this works, you should fix it, maybe using a `data` attribute instead.

If you have lots of elements, you should use [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  let div = this.closest('div').id;
  let data = {};
  data[this.id] = true;
  console.log(`clicked ${this.id} inside div ${div}`);
  console.log(data);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
  <h3 id='barTitle' class='bar'>Bar name</h3>
  <button id='monday'> Monday </button>
  <button id='tuesday'> Tuesday </button>
  <button id='wednesday'> Wednesday </button>
  <button id='thursday'> Thursday </button>
  <button id='friday'> Friday </button>
  <button id='saturday'> Saturday </button>
  <button id='sunday'> Sunday </button>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
  <h3 id='barTitle' class='bar'>Bar name</h3>
  <button id='monday'> Monday </button>
  <button id='tuesday'> Tuesday </button>
  <button id='wednesday'> Wednesday </button>
  <button id='thursday'> Thursday </button>
  <button id='friday'> Friday </button>
  <button id='saturday'> Saturday </button>
  <button id='sunday'> Sunday </button>
</div>
```